# Changing icCube result cache configuration

Tags: iccube

I'm trying to increase the cache value from 16 MB to 64 MB but the log always shows 16 MB. I've tried different values from 2 MB to 512 MB. What is wrong with my configuration file? Is there a size limit?

```
<resultCacheConfiguration>
<mode>MEMORY</mode>
<size>64</size>
<gvi>true</gvi>
<xmla>false</xmla>
<cachingPolicy>
<classname>crazydev.iccube.olap.eval.cache.result.cache.OlapResultCacheImmediatePolicy</classname>
<!-- <classname>crazydev.iccube.olap.eval.cache.result.cache.OlapResultCacheBufferedPolicy</classname> -->
<param>
<name>bufferedRequestCount</name>
<value>1024</value>
</param>
</cachingPolicy>
</resultCacheConfiguration>
```

The log dump:

```
[                main] [ INFO] (14:18:02.358)                    icCube.loadReadingQueueSize : 32
[                main] [ INFO] (14:18:02.358)                     icCube.loadReadingRowBatch : 1000
[                main] [ INFO] (14:18:02.359)                  icCube.loadReadingThreadCount : 2 (actual:2)
[                main] [ INFO] (14:18:02.359)                        icCube.localeIdentifier : SystemDefault (2048)
[                main] [ INFO] (14:18:02.359)         icCube.maxBufferSizeForCachingIterator : 65536
[                main] [ INFO] (14:18:02.359)                  icCube.maxTablePartitionCount : 1024
[                main] [ INFO] (14:18:02.359)                  icCube.maxUnresolvedRowsCount : 65535
[                main] [ INFO] (14:18:02.360)                 icCube.mdxEvalFastNonEmptyAxis : true
[                main] [ INFO] (14:18:02.360)             icCube.mdxEvalLambdaProcessingMode : SET_CALC | PARALLEL_AXIS
[                main] [ INFO] (14:18:02.360)                    icCube.mdxEvalMeasureVector : true
[                main] [ INFO] (14:18:02.360)               icCube.mdxEvalUnknownMemberError : true
[                main] [ INFO] (14:18:02.361)      icCube.olapEngineSimultaneousRequestCount : -1 (actual:4)
[                main] [ INFO] (14:18:02.361)                      icCube.requestCacheActive : true
[                main] [ INFO] (14:18:02.361)           icCube.requestCacheAssertConsistency : false
[                main] [ INFO] (14:18:02.361)                     icCube.requestCacheMaxSize : 500000
[                main] [ INFO] (14:18:02.361)                        icCube.requestCacheMode : ALL
[                main] [ INFO] (14:18:02.361)                         icCube.resultCacheMode : MEMORY
[                main] [ INFO] (14:18:02.362)                       icCube.resultCachePolicy : crazydev.iccube.olap.eval.cache.result.cache.OlapResultCacheBufferedPolicy
[                main] [ INFO] (14:18:02.362)                         icCube.resultCacheSize : 16
[                main] [ INFO] (14:18:02.362)                      icCube.selectCellMaxCount : -1
[                main] [ INFO] (14:18:02.362)                            icCube.toStrMaxSize : 4096
[                main] [ INFO] (14:18:02.362)                              icCube.visualMode : NON_VISUAL_TOTAL
[                main] [ INFO] (14:18:02.363)         icCube.visualTotalsIntermediateMembers : true

[     docs-on-startup] [ INFO] (14:18:07.564)            max mem : 16.0MB
[     docs-on-startup] [ INFO] (14:18:07.565)  max mem per cache : 4096KB
[     docs-on-startup] [ INFO] (14:18:07.565)  min mem per cache : 128KB
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your resultCacheConfiguration is correct; you can check the actual cache configuration using the Monitoring/Runtime application (see picture attached).

[image]

The log file is about the old way of configuring that cache in icCube.xml and as you've no such property in the icCube.xml file you're seeing default values.

Comment: The display is very informative. I've found everything I needed. Thank you.